# When spinning up a Compose service using the --scale option, how to add additional instances without interrupting running ones

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've spin up N instance of an `app` service using a Compose file.

Let's N=4:

```
$ docker-compose up --detach --scale app=4 app
```

Now I'd like to run more of them, as if I had started them all at once.

Let's say I want to start 6 *more* instances on-the-fly, so that I end up having 10 instances running, as if I launched this command at the very first place:

```
$ docker-compose up --detach --scale app=10 app
```

How could I achieve that?

I tested launching 6 mores this way:

```
$ docker-compose up --detach --scale app=6 app
```

But this seems to recreate the former, interrupting what they were working on.

How could I add more instances?

Answer (score 0):

The scale option sets the total number of replicas, not the number of replicas to add. So if you have 4 running, and set `app=6`, it will create 2 additional app containers. To avoid recreating the existing containers, use the `--no-recreate` option:

```
docker-compose up --detach --scale app=6 --no-recreate app
```